# $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ can't be a smooth fiber bundle of a $1$-dimensional smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

This question was stated during a lesson where I asked my professor if every two dimensional smooth manifold arises as a tangent bundle of some one dimensional smooth manifold. My professor said that something more strong happens since for example $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ can't be a smooth fiber bundle of any one dimensional smooth manifold.

I already know that if such smooth fiber bundle exists then the base space must be $S^1$ since every smooth one dimensional manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1,$ but being $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ compact implies that the base space must be compact, hence diffeomorphic to $S^1.$

Restating my problem, I want to prove:

> There is no smooth fiber bundle with base space $S^1$ and total space $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R}).$

I've proved this using algebraic topology (concretely at the level of fundamental groups) but my professor said that he prefers a solution with the tools of differential geometry, something like studying the possible fibers and so on. At this point I don't know how to proceed.

I hope someone could help me on this.

Comment: By compactness, the fibers are also $S^1$. I'm not sure what your professor is looking for.

Comment: With regard to your original question, tangent bundles — indeed, any vector bundles — are necessarily noncompact manifolds.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Could you give more details on proving that the fibre must be $S^1$? I still don't know how to prove it without algebraic topology. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I think this is the best way to conclude my first question. Thanks!

Comment: As you said, every one-dimensional manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$. If the fiber were $\mathbb{R}$, the total space would be non-compact, which $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not.